# How do I create a table in word that changes color depending on the text input?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to make a table that three values can be assigned to:
"no conflicts" (green background), "slight conflicts" (yellow background) and "big conflicts" (red background) via a dropdown menue. Via the developer tools I was able to find the dropdown menue and configure it corrctly. Now I Thought that I could use the "Macros" feature of word to facilitate the color change in the table itself.
I used the following code that I found on another thread and edited, but somehow it doesn´t do what it should...

Idk why the code that follows isn´t completely in this box...

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Farbänderung()
    Dim tTable As Table
    Dim cCell As Cell

    For Each tTable In ActiveDocument.Range.Tables
        For Each cCell In tTable.Range.Cells
            If InStr(cCell.Range.Text, "no conflicts") <> 0 Then
                Selection.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
                Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
                Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGreen
            Else
            If InStr(cCell.Range.Text, "slight conflict") <> 0 Then
                Selection.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
                Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
                Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
            Else
            If InStr(cCell.Range.Text, "big conflict") <> 0 Then
                Selection.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
                Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
                Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            End If
            End If
    Next
    Next
End Sub
```

This function colors every selected field green regardless of the input value.

Could someone help me? The end goal would be to have this in a fillable word form so if it could be automatised like in the conditional programming in excel that would be ideal but i do settle for a functioning macro ;-)

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16505-change-color-according-dropdown-selection.html#post47254

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues with your code:

- your If-structure is wrong - you should receive a compile error. Check documentation of how to use `ElseIf`
- you apply the background color to the selection - not to the cell you are checking

Furthermore it is always better to not repeat code if not necessary.

I fixed these issues:

```vb
Sub Farbänderung()
    Dim tTable As Table
    Dim cCell As Cell, color As WdColor

    For Each tTable In ActiveDocument.Range.Tables
        For Each cCell In tTable.Range.Cells
            With cCell
                If InStr(.Range.Text, "no conflicts") <> 0 Then
                    color = wdColorGreen
                ElseIf InStr(cCell.Range.Text, "slight conflict") <> 0 Then
                    color = wdColorYellow
                ElseIf InStr(cCell.Range.Text, "big conflict") <> 0 Then
                    color = wdColorRed
                Else
                    color = wdColorAutomatic
                End If
                
                If color <> wdColorAutomatic Then
                    With .Shading
                        .Texture = wdTextureNone
                        .ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
                        .BackgroundPatternColor = color
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I am a total beginner and was completly lost... Is there any way to automate that the code is run for every time the value is changed? (So if i change my value from "no conflicts" to "big conflicts" that the color automaticly changes without having to manually run the macro again?)

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54917202 (If my answer helped you: don't forget to accept it :-) )

Comment: I am sorry, The link has not helped me... is there another way (either of explanation or to do it)?... sorry english is not my first language and i am reeeally new to this